# Percentage similarity between a set of strings

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to compute the similarity in percentages between an input string and a given collection of string.  I have seen examples using hamming distance and levenshtein distance. But these only take into consideration two stings.

My Question: It is possible to compute the above for multiple stings at once? ( I have set of stored strings, I get a new input sting and I want to find out how similar old sting are to the new one, or the sting that matches say 90%). I beleive hamming distance would be appropriate as all the strings are of equal length.

Eg: Assume input: A T T A C G C T

```
         Existing: A A T T G T C
                   A C T T G T C
                   C A T T G T C
```

While there are many similar questions answered, I have not been able to find one that takes this into consideration. Maybe someone can help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why you put sql tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this : [levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.levenshtein.php)

Check the doc to have example, hope it s help you.